# Multivariate cummulative sum

Tags: r, cumsum

Assume one wished to calculate a cumulative sum based on a multivariate condition, `all(Z[i] <= x)`, for all i over a multivariate grid x. One may obviously implement this naively

```
cSums <- numeric(nrow(x))
for(i in seq(nrow(x))){
   for(j in seq(nrow(Z))){
        if(all(Z[j, ] <= x[i, ]))
            cSums[i] <- cSums[i] + R[j] # <== R is a single vector to be summed
   }
}
```

which would be somewhere around `O((n*p)^2)`, or slightly faster by iteratively subsetting the columns

```
cSums <- numeric(nrow(x))
for(i in seq(nrow(x))){
    indx <- seq(nrow(Z))
    for(j in seq(ncol(Z))){
        indx <- indx[which(Z[indx, j] <= x[i, j])]
    }
    cSums[i] <- sum(R[indx])
}
```

but this still worst-case as slow as the naive-implementation. How could one improve this to achieve faster performance, while still allowing an undefined number of columns to be compared?

## Dummy data and Reproducible example

```
var1 <- c(3,3,3,5,5,5,4,4,4,6)
var2 <- rep(seq(1,5), each = 2)
Z <- cbind(var1, var2)
x <- Z
R <- rep(1, nrow(x))
# Result using either method.
#[1] 2 2 3 4 6 6 5 5 6 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` row-wise and compare every row with every other row and count how many of them satidy the criteria.

```
apply(Z, 1, function(x) sum(rowSums(Z <= as.list(x)) == length(x)))
#[1]  2  2  3  4  6  6  5  5  6 10
```

Similar approach can also be performed using `sapply` + `split`

```
sapply(split(Z, seq_len(nrow(Z))), function(x) 
                sum(rowSums(Z <= as.list(x)) == length(x)))
```

**data**

```
var1 <- c(3,3,3,5,5,5,4,4,4,6)
var2 <- rep(seq(1,5), each = 2)
Z <- data.frame(var1, var2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As a side note, the speedup here is from the vectorization of the second loop through `sum(rowSums(Z <= as.list(x)) == length(x))` rather than the apply. Pre-allocation a vector for the output and using a for loop removes a slight overhead from the apply function. But the answer is great and helped out a ton. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`outer` is your friend, just `Vectorize` your comparison. `colSums` yields the  desired result then. Should be fast.

```
f <- Vectorize(function(k, l) all(Z[k, ] <= x[l, ]))

res <- colSums(outer(1:nrow(Z), 1:nrow(x), f))
res
# [1]  2  2  3  4  6  6  5  5  6 10
```

#### Data

```
x <- Z <- structure(c(3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 5, 5), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("var1", 
"var2")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jay. Sadly vectorize causes quite a bit of overhead, which increases quite drastically with the dimension of the problem. In addition this type of problem suffers from the curse of dimensionality. Basically I'd run out of memory. Although it (might) be faster in smaller problems, for larger problems it becomes untenable. However thanks for the effort!